# PayPal API Sandbox - "For security reasons, this page is no longer available"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm working with the PayPal API and am trying to create an account as shown [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/gs_AdaptiveAccounts/).

The request is made to `https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/CreateAccount`.

I'm able to send a valid request and get a response indicating success back but the redirect URL that's also returned as part of the response payload (which according to their docs is supposed to take the user to a PayPal sign up/registration page) is directing them to the following:

[image: Redirect page]

I've been unable to find anything on Stackoverflow or Google regarding this. Has anyone encountered this before? I'm assuming that even though it's a sandbox environment it should allow me to simulate the workflow somehow. I've tried with both the default sandbox credentials as well as for my own environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was due to the IP address header in the request. The default configuration is:

```
-H "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 192.0.2.0"
```

While testing on localhost, I changed it to:

```
-H "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 127.0.0.1"
```

Also had to ensure that the email address didn't already have an account registered to it - in which case it would lead to a login page instead of the registration page (which is a little poorly designed in my opinion since you can't really test without making new accounts each time).